# Invalid Length Parameter Passed to the Right Function After Converting MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting an error

> Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function

when I run this sql script

```
SELECT count(*) as count 
FROM damage_reports AS a 
JOIN comments AS b ON b.v_id = a.v_id AND b.comment_txt LIKE ('Damage Report #%') 
JOIN VIN AS c ON a.v_id = c.v_id 
JOIN damage_report_entries AS d ON a.dr_id = d.dr_id 

WHERE LEFT(RIGHT(b.comment_txt, LEN(b.comment_txt) - CHARINDEX('#',b.comment_txt)), 
CHARINDEX(':',RIGHT(b.comment_txt, LEN(b.comment_txt) - CHARINDEX('#',b.comment_txt) -1)))=
convert(nvarchar(10), d.dr_id)
AND a.dateIncident BETWEEN '2017-04-26' AND '2017-06-05'
```

The RIGHT function that is causing the issue is the 2nd RIGHT. If I remove the -1 it runs but gives wrong result. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add sample data that reproduces the error.

Comment: well... it's getting a NULL or neg value most likely. Find the one records that give the CORRECT result when you remove the -1. That's going to be your problem records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have some data which doesn't conform to the RIGHT clause. When you omit the -1 at the end you will get results, though some of the strings will be blank or NULL - this is what you're referring to when you are saying that you are getting incorrect data without the -1.

In order for you to catch those values, please try running the following query against your database. Whatever results you get here are the ones responsible for messing up your query.

```
SELECT 
    count(*) as [count ]
FROM damage_reports AS a 
JOIN comments AS b ON b.v_id = a.v_id AND b.comment_txt LIKE ('Damage Report #%') 
JOIN VIN AS c ON a.v_id = c.v_id 
JOIN damage_report_entries AS d ON a.dr_id = d.dr_id 
WHERE LEN(LEFT(
    RIGHT(b.comment_txt, LEN(b.comment_txt) - CHARINDEX('#',b.comment_txt)), 
    CHARINDEX(':',RIGHT(b.comment_txt, LEN(b.comment_txt) - CHARINDEX('#',b.comment_txt)))))<= 0
AND a.dateIncident BETWEEN '2017-04-26' AND '2017-06-05'
```

Once you get these results, you'll have the requisite records which you'll need to tweak your join.

Best of luck.

Comment: When I run that I get this error `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '12378:' to data type int`

Comment: I ran the query and it runs but gives a 0 result which is wrong. I know this because when I ran for all-time (2011 -2017) the result is 4 and should be 6567

Comment: Look at those 4 records - it seems as if they are the ones which are causing the trouble here

Comment: Well removing them still gives me bad results, to which I mean 0 now for any dates

Comment: I ran the updated query and the results are 0. Now I did change the query to be >=0 and got the results of 166 but with the live MySQL Server, the results are 235

Comment: You didn't write that you're using MySQL. Please be clear with the tags in the future. At this time, in order for me to continue helping you, you'll need to post some sample data. Use SQLfiddle or Rextester to post some data -  post a link here.

Comment: Im not using MySQL. I converted this script from MySQL to SQL Server but am getting these problems with it. I wrote in the title that I converted from MySQL to SQL

Comment: SQLFiddle doesnt seem to be working correctly for me. Something else?

Comment: try rextester.com

Comment: no example with b.comment_txt LIKE ('Damage Report #%')

Comment: The following has no matches: JOIN VIN AS c ON a.v_id = c.v_id  -- please add some data for that

Comment: I got it now, though I am not getting any errors now... I did need to filter out the date clause, as you gave me data for another date. Can you please give me the comment record which did the following as mentioned in your question: _The RIGHT function that is causing the issue is the 2nd RIGHT. If I remove the -1 it runs but gives wrong result. Any help is greatly appreciated!_

Comment: When I run it without the -1 I get 0 results going all the way back so not sure what to do here.

Comment: Ok... I was able to replicate an error something to that effect. Check if you have a comment missing the colon. try `select * from comments where comment_txt like 'Damage Report #%' and comment_txt not like '%:%'`

Comment: Wow you are good ... 2 results. `Damage Report #125 Does not apply to this unit. Damage Report #10628 is in reference to gs379312`